# What does hypothesis with operator with question mark mean

Tags: coq

I've been working with the Coq proof assistant for the past few weeks, but I encountered something special today. I'm working my way through the exercises of the "Types and programming languages" book by Benjamin Pierce. In one of these exercises I have to proof for some self-made programming language (Imp in Pierce's exercises) that a specific hoare triplet is valid. I've almost finished this proof, but I'm stuck at a point where I have to proof that the following is valid `st X <= st Y` where st is some state, and st X returns a value stored at Id X in the state.

My hypothesis state the following:

```
st : state
H : (st X <=? st Y) = true
```

My question now is what the ? means in `(st X <=? st Y) = true` and how I can use this theorem to prove the goal (which seems almost the same to as H?)?

Comment: Don't you mean the "Software Foundations" book?

Comment: @ArthurAzevedoDeAmorim Yes indeed. I use both books and was a bit confused for a moment :)

Comment: Since `st X` and `st Y` are natural numbers, you can simplify your question into: What does `?` mean in `<=?` and how do I prove `forall m n, (m <=? n) = true -> m <= n.` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need is `apply Nat.leb_le`, which states that `(n <=? m) = true <-> n <= m` (depending on your imports, it might require a different prefix). The natural question is, how do you figure that out?

First, you can normally get information about a definition with `Print ident.` (which shows the body) or `Check ident.` (which only shows the type - useful for theorems). However, `<=?` isn't an identifier, it's notation, so you instead need to Locate its definition:

```
Locate "<=?".
(* Notation
   "x <=? y" := Nat.leb x y : nat_scope (default interpretation) *)
```

Then, we can find relevant theorems:

```
Search Nat.leb.
(* ... (9 other theorems *)
   Nat.leb_le: forall n m : nat, (n <=? m) = true <-> n <= m
   ...
 *)
```

We can also skip the intermediate step and do a more specific search. Note that you need quotes around the notation.

`Search "<=?" true.
(*
... (three other theorems)
Nat.leb_le: forall n m : nat, (n <=? m) = true <-> n <= m
*)`

Comment: Thank you very much! I didn't know of these tricks and they are really helpful :)

Comment: For an ident, I think `About` is preferable to `Check`.